# Turning On "Negative Testing" for Sandbox paypal (NVP/SOAP API)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to turn on "Negative Testing" for sandbox paypal testing. As currently paypal purchases becomes successfull even if there is zero balance in Paypal, it automatically deducts it from credit Union card.

But I can't find the option to turn ON "Negative testing" in my Profile tab of sandbox facilitator account as described [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/nt-classic/).

[screenshot of my profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNQks.png)

Comment: Which PayPal API are you using? NVP/SOAP or REST?

Comment: I am using NVP/SOAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this option here: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts/

1. Click on arrow close to the email address of the business account (to show the links)
2. Click on the **profile** link
3. Go to settings tab
4. You should be able to set **Negative Testing** to **ON**

**Screenshots:**
Profile link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6krFz.jpg
Negative Testing option: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDf1P.jpg